# how to define constant variables in header files in C language

Tags: c

I define several structures in a header file
some structures have all thier members with constant values and some other structures have parts of
their members with constant values

for those structures with constant members, is it possible to define a constant variable 
in the header file?

like in a header file   tcp_option.h

```
struct tcp_opt_nop
{
    _uint_t kind;  /* it has a constant value 0x01*/
}
```

so I want to define a constant variable, like

```
struct tcp_opt_nop opt_nop={ 0x01};
```

and then this variable can be used by other source files

Comment: Do you mean a `define` directive?

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: Please show some code you are trying to compile. You can edit your original post and put the code in.

Comment: If you like down vote, don't modify your question. If not then provide some code example...

Comment: yes, I have added some example codes.

Comment: "constant variable".  Interesting wording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `extern` you variable.

`.h` file:

```
#ifndef HDR_H
#define HDR_H

typedef struct 
{
    int  kind;  /* it has a constant value 0x01*/
} tcp_opt_nop;

extern const tcp_opt_nop  opt_nop;

#endif
```

`.c` file:

```
#include "hdr.h"

const tcp_opt_nop opt_nop = {0x01};
```

main file:

```
#include "hdr.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%i\n", opt_nop.kind);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ah, I got it, you mean I need to create a `tcp_option.c` file, just wondering if I forgot to include `tcp_option.c` when compiling, what will happend. how to make me not forget the `tcp_option.c` file?

Comment: You shouldn't include `.c` file, you must link it. If you are using an IDE you should add it to your project.

Comment: Why not `static const tcp_opt_nop opt_nop = {0x01};` in _hdr.h_? Assuming the address of the variable is not needed, then will this not make optimiser's job easier?

Answer (score -3):

yes, you can define. See the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct temp
{
    int a;
} temp;
const temp test={5};
int main()
{
    printf("%d",test.a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: they are in the same file, what I want to do is to define a independent header file

Comment: yes, even that is possible. just copy the declaration of the struct and definition of temp to another file,say, temp.h and simply #include "temp.h" to your source file, where you want to use those...

Comment: then if I include this header file in many source files within the same project, will this const variable be defined multiple times? I think an `extern` should be added?

Comment: then use

`#ifndef TEMP_H`


`#define TEMP_H`

at the top of your header file...


and at the bottom of the file put `#endif`

Comment: Copying this into a header file will result in a linker error if you use it from two different source files.

Comment: he said if I use #ifndef TEMP_H #define TEMP_H, it will be fine?

Comment: @user1944267: No, that won't protect against the linker errors. But M.M.'s answer is correct.